# select oid from order_details where UserName= '"+uname+"' order by oid desc limit 1

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, netbeans

What is the syntax error in the query:

select oid from order_details where UserName= '"+uname+"' order by oid desc limit 1;
Here i am gettin error of syntax.... plz help!!! what is the error???
Full Code:

```
<%@page import="javax.validation.constraints.Null"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%> 
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
String languages;
int price;
int tot;
String[] lang=request.getParameterValues("dish");
String event=request.getParameter("eve");
String date=request.getParameter("date");
String place=request.getParameter("place"); 
String person=request.getParameter("PERSON");
String uname=(String)session.getAttribute("username"); 
String oid="0";
int row=32;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ready to serve", "root", "");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("insert into order_details(event_date,PLACE,NO_OF_PERSON,Event,UserName)values('"+date+"','"+place+"','"+person+"','"+event+"','"+uname+"')");
String getoid= "select oid from order_details where UserName= '"+uname+"' order by oid desc limit 1";

ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(getoid);
if(rs.next())
{
oid=rs.getString(1);
}
int noof=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("PERSON"));
tot=0;
ResultSet pric= st.executeQuery("select sum(a.price) from menu a,dorder b where a.dish=b.dish");
while(pric.next())
{
tot=pric.getInt(1)* noof;
}
for(int i=0;i<lang.length;i++)
{
    languages = lang[i];
    st.executeUpdate("insert into dorder values('"+languages+"','"+oid+"','"+uname+"')"); 
}
String totin="update order_details set tot='"+tot+"'where oid="+getoid;
st.executeUpdate(totin);
out.println("Data is successfully inserted into database.");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1)  code in JSP == BAD.  2) creation of SQL command in this manner is a likely candidate for SQL Injection.  3) Indent you code so that it is easy to read

Comment: data is inserting in database but value of 'tot' is not being updated in the table......//

Answer (score 0):

You need some spaces in the update command

```
 String totin="update order_details set tot = '"+tot+"' where oid = "+getoid;
```

According to the below error, the `Select` also seems wrong

try

```
select oid from order_details where UserName = 'fred' order by oid desc limit 1
```

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select oid from order_details where UserName= 'rahul0190' order by oid desc limi' at line 1
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select oid from order_details where UserName= 'rahul0190' order by oid desc limi' at line 1

Comment: well Dude, that is a select statement, not an update.  Try adding a space before the `=`

Comment: But what that error means ...... data is inserting into database properly but its still generating error in select query.....

Comment: String totin="update order_details set tot='"+tot+"'where oid="+getoid;
st.executeUpdate(totin);          Its not updating the value of tot  column in database.......

Comment: The error you posted above is related to the select.  The update you have just posted has not been changed to reflect my answer I gave.

Comment: see my answer.  Again, you need some spaces.  If this does solve your problem then lets us know what the error is.

Comment: add a spacing here too `String totin="update order_details set tot='"+tot+"' where oid="+getoid;`